# Laravel. Отсутствие временных меток в методе pivot

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Имеются 2 таблицы, которые связаны отношениями many-to-many, в миграции к связанной таблице имеются временные метки, которые успешно заполняются фейковыми данными. Проблема заключается в том, что когда я пытаюсь вывести результат на экране, у меня присутствуют только ключи двух таблиц, связанных отношениями, а временные метки полностью отсутствуют, хотя мне нужно оперировать именно ими

миграция связанной таблицы:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('employee_pass_number', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->foreignId('pass_number_id')->index()->constrained('pass_numbers')->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->foreignId('employee_id')->index()->constrained('employees')->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->dateTime('created_at')->nullable()->default(DBAlias::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()'));
            $table->dateTime('deleted_at')->nullable();
        });
    }
```

Отрезок кода с выводом

```
$passNumber = PassNumber::query()->where('card_number', '=', \request()->get('pass_number'))
            ->with('employees')
            ->first();

        if ($passNumber) {
            $passNumber->update([
                'is_active' => false,
                'deleted_at' => now()
            ]);
            $passNumber->save();
                foreach ($passNumber->employees as $employee){
                    dd($employee->pivot->created_at);
                }
```

В данном запросе выводом на экран будет NULL, а если убрать created_at, то получится:

```
 +incrementing: false
  #guarded: []
  #connection: null
  #table: "employee_pass_number"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:2 [▼
    "pass_number_id" => 2
    "employee_id" => 2
  ]
  #original: array:2 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: false
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  +pivotParent: App\Models\PassNumber {#1089 ▶}
  #foreignKey: "pass_number_id"
  #relatedKey: "employee_id"
```

Прошу обратить внимание на строку +timestamps: false, почему она возникает, если у меня есть метки в миграции

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В модели `PassNumber` должно быть определено отношение с указанием дополнительных полей pivot

```
public function employees()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Employe::class)->withPivot('created_at', 'deleted_at');
}
```

Comment: Да, это правильный ответ

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ, он оказался верным

Answer (score 0):

```
 $table->dateTime('created_at')->nullable()->default(DBAlias::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()'));
```

Зачем? в Laravel е же все это есть из коробки, укажите в миграции вместо этой записи

```
 $table->timestamps();
```